# Building Responsive Components in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design

I am using the [react-responsive module](https://github.com/contra/react-responsive) to build a responsive layout in react. My render function returns this

```
<div>
    <Desktop>
        ...
    </Desktop>
    <Phone>
        ...
    </Phone>
</div>
```

Where `Desktop` and `Phone` are defined as

```
export class Phone extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    renderChild(matches) {
        if (matches) {
            return this.props.children
        }

        return null;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MediaQuery query="only screen and (min-width : 480px)">
                 {(matches) => (this.renderChild(matches))}
            </MediaQuery>
        )
    }
}

export class Desktop extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    renderChild(matches) {
        if (matches) {
            return this.props.children
        }

        return null;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MediaQuery query="only screen and (min-width : 992px)">
                {(matches) => (this.renderChild(matches))}
            </MediaQuery>
        )
    }
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that because both queries are matched, the components are rendered both as what's in the desktop component, and what's in the phone component. I'd like it to only render What's in Desktop when desktop matches, and what's in Phone when phone matches. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `(max-width: 991px)`?